# Trigger Alerts for Pods memory Utilization in Redhat Openshift

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I intend to configure alerts for some pods in Openshift
Like An email will trigger if a certain pod reaches 80% or more memory utilization.

Is this possible in Openshift?
I tried to check references online but only found how to configure email notification but nothing for memory utilization..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First you'll want to craft the prometheus query to observe the memory. If you go under Workloads->Pods-->Metrics then click on the memory usage chart you will get a query that is quite close. But that's going to probably be querying for a specific pod and you may want to include a wildcard if we assume that you are using a Deployment or similar. e.g. a prometheus query something like `sum(container_memory_working_set_bytes{pod=~'mypodname-.+',namespace='mynamespcae',container='',}) BY (POD)`

You can then craft an Alert based on that as defined in [the documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.11/monitoring/managing-alerts.html#managing-alerting-rules-for-user-defined-projects_managing-alerts). In short you'll have to hand craft the YAML of your Alert based on your PromQL, and you'll have to set up an alert receiver. (e.g. email). You will also have to make sure you permissions to do all of the above.

I'll mention that creating such an alert does have a "funny smell" to me.  It feels like treating a pod as a pet, rather than cattle. After all, what's the point of this alert? Could not some sort of solution be automated with standard K8S tools, such as an autoscaler or killing/restarting the pod?